# Decoding a hex encoded string using a stringstream

Tags: c++, encoding, hex, stringstream

It's easy to hex encode a string using a stringstream, but is it possible to do the reverse and decode the resulting string with a stringstream?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::string test = "hello, world";

  std::stringstream ss; 
  ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  for (unsigned ch : test)
    ss << std::setw(2) << int(ch);

  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not looking to bit shift the bytes directly or use old c functions such as the scanf family of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite as easy, if you just have a stream of hexadecimal digits with no separator. You can use [`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) or [`std::basic_istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to extract two digits at a time, and then use e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert to an integer which can then be type-casted to a `char`.

Comment: You'd also need to append 0x to each pair, I believe.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski No, the prefix is optional for `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 1):

It is *if* you put some sort of separator between the numbers. Just for example, let's start by changing your code to insert a space between each byte of output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::string test = "hello, world";

  std::stringstream ss; 
  ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  for (unsigned ch : test)
    ss << std::setw(2) << int(ch) << " ";

  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Then, let's write a little program to read that data from cin, and print it out as characters again:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int i;
    while (std::cin >> std::hex >> i)
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(i);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run these with the first piped to the second, I get `hello, world` as the output.

Obviously enough, reading the data from a `stringstream` works about the same as reading from `std::cin` -- I used cin so I could demonstrate while leaving your code nearly intact.